# How to use Select2 multi-select with redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jquery-select2, redux-form

How can I use Select plugin with Redux-Form?

Tried:

```
<Field component="select2" className="select2" multiple={true}>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
<Field>
```

and didnt work

Comment: Select2 is a jquery's plugin and not a reactjs plugin, so you can't really use it

Comment: That's not true. I am using it with react already. I just cant implement it with redux-form in particular

Comment: Are you using select2 or react-select2? They are not the same

Comment: Your tags says you are using jquery-select2, and you should not be using it with react.